# R row-wise counting the number of specific occurrences in a column and fill a column that shows the incremental occurrences

Tags: r

I want to count the number of a specific instance in a column and fill a column that shows the row-wise increase.
In the example below, I want to count number of `TRUE`s in the column `TrueFalse` and insert it into (or create) column `TRUES`. In other words, the column `TRUES` increases incrementally when `TrueFalse==TRUE`. The same goes for the column `FALSES`.
the counting should restart when `ID` changes.

```
data<-read.table(text="
ID    TrueFalse   
1        NA        
1       TRUE       
1       TRUE       
1        NA        
1       FALSE      
1       FALSE      
2       TRUE       
2       FALSE      
2       NA         
2       NA         
2       FALSE      
2       TRUE       
2       FALSE",header=T)      

result:

ID    TrueFalse   TRUES      FALSES
1        NA         0         0
1       TRUE        1         0
1       TRUE        2         0
1        NA         2         0
1       FALSE       2         1
1       FALSE       2         2
2       TRUE        1         0
2       FALSE       1         1
2       NA          1         1
2       NA          1         1
2       FALSE       1         2 
2       TRUE        2         2
2       FALSE       2         3
```

Please note that `TrueFalse` column can be character for counting rather than only TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `replace` `NA` values and count using `cumsum` :

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Trues = cumsum(replace(TrueFalse, is.na(TrueFalse), 0)), 
         Falses = cumsum(!replace(TrueFalse, is.na(TrueFalse), TRUE)))


#      ID TrueFalse Trues Falses
#   <int> <lgl>     <dbl>  <int>
# 1     1 NA            0      0
# 2     1 TRUE          1      0
# 3     1 TRUE          2      0
# 4     1 NA            2      0
# 5     1 FALSE         2      1
# 6     1 FALSE         2      2
# 7     2 TRUE          1      0
# 8     2 FALSE         1      1
# 9     2 NA            1      1
#10     2 NA            1      1
#11     2 FALSE         1      2
#12     2 TRUE          2      2
#13     2 FALSE         2      3
```

If we have character values in `TrueFalse` we can use :

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Trues = cumsum(replace(TrueFalse, is.na(TrueFalse), '') == 'TRUE'),
         Falses = cumsum(replace(TrueFalse, is.na(TrueFalse), '') == 'FALSE'))
```